# 1-hot encoding when the classes are numbers

Tags: python, classification, multiclass-classification

I've got a little problem with classification where classes are numbers. I have 4 classes : 0 - 200 - 250 - 300.

I'm using this as the optimizer :

```
model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              loss     = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics  = ['accuracy'])
```

and this as the last layer :

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(301,  activation='softmax'))
```

Is there a way to transform the last layer to :

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,  activation='softmax'))
```

without changing the classes names and if possible with 1-hot encoding ?

Thanks in advance

Edit : the full model is here

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(n_size,n_features))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,  activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(301,  activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              loss     = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics  = ['accuracy'])
```

but it's just a draft of a model, I'm trying to solve that problem first before upgrading the model

Comment: You have 4 classes numbered as  (0 , 200 , 250 , 300), right ?

Comment: yes. my y (what the model has to learn) is a list of only those 4 numbers

Comment: Can you please include the code of model also in the question

Comment: I edited it to include the full model. But as I say in that edit, it's just a draft of a model, I'm trying to solve that first problem before upgrading it

Comment: Where is this layer `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(301,  activation='softmax'))` ?

Comment: oups sorry, I made a mistake when editing, it's corrected now

Comment: print this: `model.output_shape` to check your output shape

Comment: I get this : (None, 301). The thing is, since there are only 4 classes, I'd like the last layer to be 4, but when I do that, it says that 300 is outside of the range [0,4)

Comment: What is your n_size,n_features?

Comment: 30 and 10 because I have to regroup 30 elements of a time series that have 10 features each

Comment: Change last layer to `model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,  activation='softmax'))` Your output will be of shape `(None, 30, 4)`

Comment: as I said, doing this create this problem :  Received a label value of 200 which is outside the valid range of [0, 4).  Label values: 0 200 0 0 300 0 250 250 250 250

Comment: number of classes should be your output unit, as you mentioned that you have 4 classes you can make it 4 otherwise if you have more classes you can put it equal to the number of classes.

Comment: That's the problem I have since the beginning ! Since the name of the class is 300, it forces me to have the last layer to 301 to include that 300 ! I'm trying to find a way for python to get that it only need 4 : one for 0, one for 200, one for 250 and one for 300

Comment: keep it 301 and put a range like if value comes within a range of 250-300 then make it 300 same goes for others.

Comment: But isn't that really badly optimized to get 301 nodes when only 4 would be needed ?

Comment: If your data is having 300 different classes and you want to convert it to 4 classes only, then either you filter data for the desired classes  which you want to obtain or put a range.

Comment: But that's the thing : there are only four classes... They have really poor names, but I can't choose those names. There is only 0, 200, 250 and 300. Nothing in between

Comment: You can easily relabel your data before training for 0-0, 1-200, 250-2, 300-3. That's it.

Comment: So there is no other ways ? you have to rename the classes ?

Comment: There might be some other possible solutions, but I know these only right now. Till now what I understood is that you have 4 classes which labels 0,200,250,300, if you are treating these classes as categorical data then you have to encode them.

Comment: That's kinda what I was asking since the beginning. But when I tried to use 1-hot with to_categorical, it created an array of size 301

Comment: Sorry, it took me a lot of time to exactly understand your question.